# Evaluation of double integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find $\int\int_T  xy \, \mathrm{d}A$ where T is the triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$.

It's really a question about the bounds and not so about evaluating the actual integral.

I would say it should be $\int_0^1\int_0^x  xy \, \mathrm{d}y \mathrm{d}x$. However the solution model given by the professor stated it should be $\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}  xy \, \mathrm{d}y \mathrm{d}x$.

But how can the upper bound for $y$ be $y=1-x$? I believe the function of the hypotenuse is given by $y=x$ and not by $y=1-x$ since the triangle would be flipped then. So which one is correct?

Comment: You're correct.